# Simple java input Strings

Tags: java, input, control-flow

```
import java.io.*;

public class ManyTickets
 {

  public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
  {
   String userInput;
   String userInput2;
   int intInput = 0;
   int intInput2 = 0;
   double total = 0.00;
   //(1) BufferedReader ageInput = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
```

Question 1: Above line works fine (1) when we change it into other place which i marked as (2).
 // but while executing  "Please enter your age"line  comes first though i create   bufferedreader object before that statement in case (1).I expect compiler  should wait for user input but it prints the statement. Though i create ageInput before try.

```
try{
    System.out.println("Please enter your age, or press '999' to exit.");

   //(2) BufferedReader ageInput = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));

    userInput = ageInput.readLine();
    intInput = Integer.parseInt (userInput);
    while (intInput != 999)
```

//Question2:While executing by 999 if i type 999 without giving space it is execute it gives some output but not exit.how to avoid whitespaces in the beginning like whatever i am giving whether 999 or      999 or999 i need same output.I need exit but not for input like 99 9; I need method to avoid whitespaces in the input(beginning).

```
{
     if (intInput < 0 || intInput > 110)
     System.out.println("Invalid entry, or your age seems a bit too high to enter buy
     tickets);
     else if (intInput <= 12)
     {
      total = total + 6;
      System.out.println("The ticket cost for 1 ticket is " + total);
     }
      else if (intInput <= 64)
     {
      total = total + 11;
      System.out.println("The ticket cost for 1 ticket is " + total);  
      }
       else
      {
       total = total + 8;
       System.out.println("The ticket cost for 1 ticket is $" + total);
       }
       System.out.println("So far, your tickets cost is: $" + total  );
       System.out.print("Would you like to buy more tickets? You can buy up to 1 more ticket    per customer! If no press 999to exit");
       userInput = ageInput.readLine();
       intInput2 = Integer.parseInt (userInput);  
        }
       }catch (NumberFormatException e){
       System.out.println("Please restart the program, and enter an integer instead!");
        }
        } 
       {
        double total = 0.0;
        System.out.println("Thank you,  The total cost for the ticket is: $" + total);
        System.out.println("Have a nice day!");
       }
       }
```

Comment: Sorry its not clear what you want from Question 1.

Comment: wherever i put the statement before try or after try it executes in the sameway//(1) BufferedReader ageInput = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));

Comment: what type of different you expect from these two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Question2:While executing by 999 if i type 999 without giving space it is execute it gives some output .how to avoid whitespaces in the beginning like whatever i am giving whether 999 or 999 i need same output. I need method to avoid whitespaces in the input.

To avoid white spaces simply remove them from strings like following:

```
userInput = ageInput.readLine().replaceAll(" ","");
intInput = Integer.parseInt (userInput);
```

> Question 1: Above line works fine (1) when we change it into other place which i marked as (2). // but while executing "Please enter your age"line comes first though i create bufferedreader object before that statement in case (1).I expect compiler should wait for user input but it prints the statement. Though i create ageInput before try.

This is too ambiguous.

Comment: Thank you for answering Q2. And Do u have any userdefined method for replaceAll or trim methods.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use Trim function to remove spaces before and after a input

```
ageInput.readLine().trim()
```

This is the definition of `trim()` method

```
public String trim() {
        int len = value.length;
        int st = 0;
        char[] val = value;    /* avoid getfield opcode */

        while ((st < len) && (val[st] <= ' ')) {
            st++;
        }
        while ((st < len) && (val[len - 1] <= ' ')) {
            len--;
        }
        return ((st > 0) || (len < value.length)) ? substring(st, len) : this;
    }
```

if you only want to remove first part remove second one

```
while ((st < len) && (val[len - 1] <= ' ')) {
    len--;
}
```

For Question 2 `readline()` is responsible for get the input. you can create `buffered` `reader` object anywhere before `readline`

Comment: and what about Question 1?

Comment: without trim any userdefined method

Comment: you only needs remove white spaces in beginning. then why are you going for a user defined method

Comment: If i use bufferedReader statement before  try block or inside try change i get same output . I need to know flow of execution

Comment: Userdefined method to improve my programmning skill

Comment: simply go see definition of trim() method

Comment: please write comments to your codes . Thank you Exbury

Answer (score 0):

Answer #1:

You are asking for user input after line 2 i.e. after print statement and hence it wait's after asking the question. If you move statement `userInput = ageInput.readLine();` before print statement (keeping Buffered reader's instantiation at line 1) then it will wait for user input and then will print the statement.

Answer #2:

You could use String's `trim()` [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) as below:

```
userInput = ageInput.readLine().trim();
```

If you need user defined function (which i would avoid), you could do something like:

```
public String myStringTrimmer() {
    int len = value.length;
    int st = 0;
    char[] val = userInput.toCharArray();
    while ((st < len) && (val[st] <= ' ')) {
        st++;
    }
    while ((st < len) && (val[len - 1] <= ' ')) {
        len--;
    }
    return ((st > 0) || (len < value.length)) ? userInput.substring(st, len) : userInput;
}
```

Comment: It is not legal here to ask like this .so i am asking in my comment .Please tell me how to improve programming step by step .

Comment: Please document on while loops. Two while loops  and return statement almas Shaikh

Comment: @karthick what do you mean by document? You already closed this question by accepting the answer, so what else you are looking for..

Comment: I mean comments on while loop and return statements like  what happens inside each line:

Comment: Is there a need now as you already done with your issue and now question is closed so please raise a new question?